# How do I read from a heap of C strings with FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi, c-str

I have a block of variable-width data in a page that I'm processing with Rust.

This block represents a heap of null terminated C strings. I have offsets into this heap the represent the starting character, reads are supposed to happen until the null is encountered.

```
let heap = *b"foobar\0baz\0quuz\0"; // Assume [u8;16] or Vec<u8>
let offset = 0;
let myCstring = something(heap, offset);
assert!( myCstring, "foobar\0" );
```

Looking at the documentation for [`ffi::CString`, I don't see anything that address the needs of `something(heap, starting_char_index)` above](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ffi/struct.CString.html).

Since this is part of a binary file format written in another language and these are C-Strings should I be trying to do this with `ffi`? Should I be just roll my own thing and ignore ffi?

Comment: What's stopping you from iterating over the "heap" and slicing on null characters? You can use `heap.slice(0)` and even convert the resulting `&[u8]` slices to `&str` ones.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo nothing, that's a reasonable answer. I think the above should be supported by std::ffi, but certainly I don't need FFI to build an importer from data, regardless of if it is C.

Comment: `std::ffi` is for interfacing with non-Rust code, and C strings are pretty much never layed out that way. It sounds like you're trying to parse a file of some sort, which is unrelated to FFI.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo they're laid out that way in every binary (and in any database that uses cstrings in the store). Declare `const static char * foo = "Foo"; const static char * bar = "Bar";` in C. Compile it. Look in the binary. They're laid out in the binary as `Foo\0Bar\0`. And wherever you have `foo` you have a pointer to the first character to that heap of strings.

Comment: And if you actually try to access the strings like in that assumption, you quickly run into undefined behavior and segfaults. Yeah, string literals may happen to be layed out that way, but no one accesses strings like that, so I'm not sure why you're expecting this to be some built-in feature.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It is a built in feature. `CStr::from_bytes_until_nul(&heap)` does exactly what I want. I also don't know why you think this even remotely rare, but you should tone down the rhetoric "no one accesses strings like that". It's very very common.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo https://stackoverflow.com/a/77410319/124486

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255829/discussion-between-colonel-thirty-two-and-evan-carroll).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`std::ffi::CStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html) to get the nul-terminated region of memory. If you are in Rust-land then [`CStr::from_bytes_until_nul(&heap[offset..])`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_bytes_until_nul) would be appropriate, but if you're coming from C-land where you just have a pointer and offset, then [`CStr::from_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_ptr) would be appropriate (with [`heap.add(offset)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.add-1)).

That would give you a `&CStr`, which is similar to `&str` just with a nul-terminator and potentially not UTF-8. If you need to claim ownership of that string, you would use `.to_owned()` to get a `CString` (similar to `String` respectively). There are further methods if you need a `&str` or `String` from that.

But since you mention its from a file, then I might skip `ffi` and just do slice manipulations to find the section bounded by nul.

Comment: Great answer I moved to using `CStr::from_bytes_until_nul(&heap)` which does exactly what I want.